# Custom SCSS based on html dir value

Tags: css, html, sass, culture

I have an asp.net MVC website, that based on a value in it's web.config can be in multiple languages.  For example, if i choose it to be in English then the html tab at the top will read

```
<html lang="en" dir="auto">
```

if i choose arabic it will read

```
<html lang="ar" dir="auto">
```

this works great for the most part, but there are definitely things in my global css file that need to be customized based on the actual 'dir' direction.  Is there a way to customize my css/scss file to act differently depending on the dir value?  can i perhaps find out what the dir value is and instead just have mulitple css classes (.menu_Left , .menu_Right) and append that value?

Or do i just need to make my own enumeration (here are the languages where dir=auto will move to the right) and do everything by hand?  I'm just trying to see what is the easiest way here.

Comment: Would it help to only do this on specific elements, like so?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp

Comment: More details and examples here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `html[lang="ar"] .menu_left { /* insert rules */ }`? That being said, you should maybe load different CSS files per language. That way the files are smaller, your performance is better and you don't have this problem to begin with.

Comment: You could also use html:lang(ar) to replace the attribute selector.